# Eclipse freezes elementary OS

Tags: eclipse

Everytime I try to run eclipse, my system crashes, it just freezes the screen and I can't do anything. I've already installed the JDK and Eclipse from the official websites, exported the var JAVA_HOME and PATH (in path just added the path to the bin folder of the JDK)

Comment: I am having the same issue try this http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/eclipse-mars-freezes-after-splash-screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are someways to solve that:

1. If you're running on 32 bit version of eclipse try to install 64 bit version.
2. Also It appears on old versions of eclipse try to install latest version. But if you are using older version than Kepler try to adding these two lines in your `eclipse.ini`‍‍‍ :

   ```
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla`
   -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=/dev/null`
   ```

(I didn't try them in Kepler or Luna maybe it works for them)

3. If you are using OpenJDK try to install Oracle JDK.
4. Try to increase memory sizes (this way solve my problem before), So adding these lines to `eclipse.ini` :

   ```
   -XX:PermSize=256m
   -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
   -Xms1024m
   -Xmx2048m
   ```

Also you can read this [article](http://blog.elzapp.com/2014/07/01/making-eclipse-kepler-and-luna-work-on-ubuntu.html) for more info.

Comment: I think that the problem is with Eclipse Mars, i've installed Eclipse Kepler and I had not any problem

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez The solution for your problem with Eclipse Mars is [here](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/1279/22)

Answer (score 1):

I am also experiencing similar problems. Disk IO pegs out at 100% until the OS crashes.

Entering the following command in the terminal will allow Eclipse Oxygen to load and run properly:

```
export SWT_GTK3=0

./eclipse &
```

I believe there is a problem that Eclipse has with the GTK toolkit.This is a temporary and annoying fix; however, I am hoping for a permanent fix.

Editing the `eclipse.ini` file didn't fix the problem. I still need to run the export command.