# Eclipse Mars freezes after splash screen

Tags: eclipse

I'm having trouble running Eclipse Mars x64 on Elementary OS. I get to the splash screen and then my computer freezes I have to hard restart it. I'm using the Oracle JDK for Java 8.

Comment: Can you run the program from terminal and paste the output here?

Comment: Just for a note, I used the solution, the same problem happened with GTK2 by the way. Also, I had changed the vm sizes, but the problem remained. Using Luna instead of Mars needed no changes or fixes as such.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a bug in the SWT porting on GTK3. There is no real solution, but there is a workaround by forcing Eclipse to use GTK2.

I assume your Eclipse folder is `/opt/eclipse` and that you don't have write permissions in this folder. Please change the commands, if your set-up differs.

There are two ways to apply this workaround, a long and explanatory way, and a short one for the lazy ;)

### 1. Modifying eclipse.ini by hand

You need to open `eclipse.ini` in your Eclipse folder:

```
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

and add the following lines:

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

It's important to add these lines before `--launcher.appendVmargs`, otherwise Eclipse will crash.

---

### 2. Using the command sed

An easier way to make these changes is to use `sed`. Copy&pase this command in your terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
sudo sed -i '/--launcher.appendVmargs/ i \--launcher.GTK_version\n2' /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini
```

---

Your Eclipse should work properly from now on.

Comment: From your comment it seems like the issue is with GTK3 so the resolution would be to force GTK2. But your instructions for editing eclipse.ini set the GTK version to 3. I had issues with this until I set it to GTK2, seems to be working now.

Comment: Ops, you are right... stupid me! I have changed the values, the answer should be correct now :)

Comment: I applied the first solution and it worked, thank you! although I would like to know what is the different between gtk2 and gtk3. Will I get a lower or worse performance to downgrading whatever that is? (if I remember correctly it's a GUI thing but I am not sure what so that's why I am asking).

Comment: also when launching eclipse I get a bunch of warning like "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"", also a Gtk-Warning about a module "pixmap" and these too: "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"", "Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0", "Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module""

is there any way I can fix these warnings?

Comment: Another option (simpler IMO) to disable GTK3 is to set an environment variable (for example in your session profile file) `SWT_GTK3=0`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, adding the lines

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

to the STS.ini file works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug (see [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1452185)). Unfortunately there is no solution yet.

Comment: Please, don't advise anyone to run an application as root.

Comment: You are right. Deleted workaround.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is because of gtk error,so its does not intializing graphics for eclipse.add type the command in the command promt-
sudo -i scratch-text-editor /opt/eclipse/eclipse.ini

and add the following line-
launcher.GTK_version
2

last of page .