# Installing Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse

How do you install Eclipse Neon? Whenever I try to install Eclipse the install version is always 3.8 I don't know what to do. Please help me. XD

Comment: Yes apt only has 3.8 in a repository.

Comment: A little off topic, but I've had a lot of problems with eclipse hanging and crashing the X server. This can be prevented by forcing the older version of GTK with `export SWT_GTK3=0`

Comment: Or with this fix: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/eclipse-mars-freezes-after-splash-screen

Answer (score 1):

Download it from
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/?osType=linux&release=undefined
extract it. Run it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't install a newest version of eclipse until you see a newest version in AppCenter
When it will be a newest version clik on it than click update and that's it.
I think you can install packages, but I'm not sure.
BTW: Don't get mad! Have a nice day!