# Eclipse and Aptana Studio 3 not working; How can I fix this issue?

Tags: release-loki, eclipse

This is the error I get. I googled for an answer but none of those worked at all.

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_3.8.1.dist/splash.bmp
-launcher /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.dist/eclipse_1503.so
-startup /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 29800b
-clean
-initialize
-vm /usr/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=/usr/share/eclipse/dropins
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar /usr/lib/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.dist.jar
```

Comment: Have you tried this? http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1276/eclipse-mars-freezes-after-splash-screen?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so after trying everything it turns out that the issue I was having was due to me using the Oracle Java 9 PPA. So I removed Oracle Java by doing sudo apt-get remove --purge java*

Then I installed the openjdk 8 and jre and the error went away and I can now run Eclipse or Aptana Studion 3.